# Where does git store the commit message

Tags: git

I was doing a commit and noticed I had made a mistake.  Since closing nano would commit the change, I force-closed the terminal.  This left the .swp file somewhere, preventing me to commit in the future:

```
*** Error in `nano': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x000000000204a990 ***
error: nano died of signal 6
error: There was a problem with the editor 'nano'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Comment: For future reference: if you delete the entire commit message in nano, git will abort the commit.

Comment: And that you can also update the commit message once committed, using `git commit --amend`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is located in the .git folder, the file is named "COMMIT_EDITMSG".

To fix the issue, go to the project's main folder and type:

```
$ rm ./.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp
```

Comment: Curious, where does git store the commit messages for the previous commits?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the commit message, you can use this command

```
git commit --amend
```

This will allow you to modify your commit, as well as your commit message on your local branch.
After modifications, push the branch to remote repository to reflect changes there.

Comment: This is helpful, but it does not answer the question.