# Where does git store commit summary and details?

Tags: git

In the `.git` folder of a repository, where can I find files storing **the text of my commit messages, including summary and details**?

[(“Summary” and “Details” are defined here.)](https://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html)

The file `COMMIT_EDITMSG` stores the latest commit message, but does not show older commits.

The log files show me older commits, but they only show the summary text, not the details text.

I also know how to view the whole commit message in the console, but I want to be able to open it in a text file.

Comment: (not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38938736/877703, as that question asks how to amend a commit)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: I think its not possible. I believe Git log /git rev list uses the latest commit message and then traverses to the old one just like a linked list.  The git references and objecs have the commit code for previous and next. So all the command needs is a commit code from which it can traverse. So this  functionality is resolved when you enter the command. So there is no easy way to see everything as a single file. But the start will be here .git\logs\refs

Comment: Note that you can run `git log` or `git rev-list` with `--grep` to search for commits whose log message contains some string; or, e.g., `git log --pretty=format:%B` to dump out the commit message (complete form, use %s and %b to split into subject/summary and body/details).

Answer (score 2):

The commit messages are stored as part of the `COMMIT` object in the database.  They may be loose objects (files named `.git/objects/<dd>/<rest-of-hash>`, where `<dd>` is two hex digits and `<rest-of-hash>` is 38 hex digits such that putting the two together makes the object ID) or they may be packed (in files under `.git/objects/pack`, with potentially many objects together in one file, sometimes in delta form).

Even loose objects are compressed, so even if you recursively grep the entire file system you likely won't find the commit message in readable form.

You can use various forms of `git log` or `git show` and capture the output to a file, I guess.  Or, if you know the commit ID, you can do something like

```
git cat-file -p <id>
```

But it's the same info log or show give.

Comment: Do you mean `git cat-file`? I don't have a `git cat-object` subcommand.

Comment: Yeah, I always get `cat-file` and `hash-object` names confused.  Updating

Comment: But both of these techniques use the command line to see the message (in fact, `git log <id>` and `git show <id>` are a lot simpler than `git cat-file -p <id>` and is colored). The question is where is the text of the commit message stored. Is it not in a plaintext file somewhere?

Comment: No, it is not in a plaintext file anywhere.  As I said in my answer.  That is why, if you need it in a plain text file, the best you can do is use the available tools (such as the command line tools) to capture it into a file.  As I said in my answer.